# how to protect and execute python code with pyarmor

Tags: python, pyarmor

i have been trying to obf some python code it with pyarmor but it ain't working it obfs on my friends computer but it wont let me obf on my computer, so we ended up getting it protected but how do I execute a protected python file with pyarmor as its coming up with some errors is there a certain way to execute it [image: python code]

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `pyarmor_runtime()` function and call it. See the code below:

```py
from pytransform import pyarmor_runtime
pyarmor_runtime()
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x50\x59\')
```

For more information see this [issue](https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor/issues/58)